# Bolding individual lines in a databound listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` is databound to a list of ints.
I'd like to bold bold a few of the items, on the basis of their value.

There are two options that come to (my) mind:

1) Use a `DataTrigger` that bolds the value if it's a match.

2) Use a class to wrap the ints and pair each int with a boolean that denotes if the value should be bolded or not.

In any case I'd need a `DataTemplate/ItemTemplate`, right?
I've played around with this but haven't got it working yet.

Cheers,
Pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in either case you'd need a `DataTemplate`. In fact, the only time you can get away with not using a `DataTemplate` is if you're happy with the default format of the text in each `ListBoxItem`.

BTW, you missed another option:

- Use a converter to determine whether the value falls in the appropriate range.

That said, if you're doing MVVM, I'd generally recommend your second option.